# Github-API: How do I plot the number of commits to a repo?

Tags: python, api, pandas, github, matplotlib

I am a Python newbie, and I am trying to plot the number of commits, per day of the week.

I have the output as a pandas dataframe. However, I am unable to figure out how to plot this data using matplotlib.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
import requests
import json
import pandas as pd
r = requests.get('https://api.github.com/repos/thisismetis/dsp/stats/commit_activity')
raw = r.text
results = json.loads(raw)
print pd.DataFrame(results)
```

Results:

```
      days  total        week
0     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]      0  1431216000
1     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0]      8  1431820800
2   [0, 19, 1, 4, 18, 8, 0]     50  1432425600
3    [0, 3, 23, 1, 0, 0, 0]     27  1433030400
4     [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]      2  1433635200
5     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]      0  1434240000
6     [0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]      2  1434844800
7     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]      0  1435449600
8     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]      0  1436054400
9     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]      0  1436659200
10    [0, 0, 8, 0, 3, 0, 0]     11  1437264000
11   [0, 3, 36, 0, 1, 9, 0]     49  1437868800
12    [0, 2, 2, 2, 5, 1, 0]     12  1438473600
13    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]      0  1439078400
14    [0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]      2  1439683200
15    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]      0  1440288000
16    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]      0  1440892800
17    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]      0  1441497600
18    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0]      3  1442102400
19    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]      0  1442707200
20    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]      0  1443312000
21    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]      0  1443916800
22    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]      0  1444521600
23   [0, 0, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0]     10  1445126400
24    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]      0  1445731200
25    [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]      1  1446336000
26    [0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 3, 0]      7  1446940800
27    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]      0  1447545600
28    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]      0  1448150400
29    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]      0  1448755200
30    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]      0  1449360000
31    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]      0  1449964800
32    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]      0  1450569600
33    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]      1  1451174400
34    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]      0  1451779200
35    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]      0  1452384000
36    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]      0  1452988800
37    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]      0  1453593600
38    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]      0  1454198400
39    [0, 0, 5, 2, 0, 0, 0]      7  1454803200
40   [0, 0, 25, 2, 0, 0, 0]     27  1455408000
41   [1, 10, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0]     14  1456012800
42    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]      0  1456617600
43    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]      0  1457222400
44    [0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0]      3  1457827200
45    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]      0  1458432000
46    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]      0  1459036800
47    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]      0  1459641600
48    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]      0  1460246400
49    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]      0  1460851200
50    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]      0  1461456000
51    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]      0  1462060800
```

Comment: what exactly do you want to plot?

Comment: I would like to plot the number of commit, for each day of the week(Sunday, Monday...Saturday), for each of the 52 weeks. I am not able to figure out how to make matplotlib use the pandas df data to plot.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/tacaswell/e95cb2d57ca3783ffc40 cell 15 and 16 contain some commit stats data munging.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can do it this way:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.week, unit='s')
df['week_no'] = df.apply(lambda x: '{:d}-{:02d}'.format(x['date'].year, x['date'].weekofyear), axis=1)
df.set_index('week_no')['total'].plot.bar()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Max for helping me with this!

Comment: Sure Max. I didn't know how to accept an answer ;) thanks for sharing it!